# Swift - Method '*()' with Objective-C selector '*' conflicts with getter for '*' from superclass 'UIView' with the same Objective-C selector

Tags: ios, swift, charts, swift2, swift3

```
 public var borderColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

I am using above code in Charts framework and i am facing error with title text.

Toolx - Xcode -8 swift 2.3 Legacy Version[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming the `borderColor` variable name. It seems the ChartViewBase is using it.

Also please change all property names from your custom classes that are conflicting with your base class variable names and property names.

This should work.. Cheers!

Comment: After doing that it gives some new errors , can we communicate over Skype ?

Comment: sure hit me on jatin.nandwani1

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it because the super class already declare that as it's property (probably `UIView` here), change it to `lineChartBorderColor` or something

Comment: Can you bit elaborate more.

Comment: Sure, in here one of your super class, which maybe the `ChartViewBase` or it's super class's `UIView` already have a property called `borderColor`, therefore if you want to override it, you have to create exactly the same return type, or give it a new name

Comment: After doing that it gives some new errors , can we communicate over Skype